# Reusing same Object variable to create multiple objects

Tags: java, performance, variables, design-patterns

Is it an alright practice to reuse the same variable to keep making new Object instances (like case 2)?

Some pseudo code:

```
//case 1:
class main {
    List<Foo> bar = new ArrayList;

    public static main(String[] args) { 

        Foo baz = new Foo(params);
        Foo baz1 = new Foo(differentParams);
        Foo baz2 = new Foo..
    } 
}

class Foo {
    Foo(params..) {
        main.bar.add(this);
    }
}

//case 2:
class main {
    List<Foo> bar = new ArrayList;

    public static main(String[] args) {

        Foo baz = new Foo(params);
        baz = new Foo(differentParams);
        baz = new Foo..
    }
}

class Foo {
    Foo(params..) {
        main.bar.add(this);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if case 2 is an okay design practice. Since in Foo I am storing the instance of the class in the list in main, I will never need the direct object variable baz1 during runtime, but will be iterating through the list to apply some logic to each object.

So my question is, is it an alright practice to reuse the same variable to keep making new Object instances (like case 2)? Conventional practices would suggest to keep a separate variable for the objects as you make them (like case 1).

This question came up in my mind when thinking about memory and whether or not doing case 2 would save more memory compared to case 1 since you are not declaring a new variable each time.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: If I'm correctly interpreting your pseudo-code, you shouldn't even use variables. But, well, it's pseudo-code...

Comment: Ive expanded the code, I dont have an actual program Ive written of this yet to get a full example

Comment: Still not valid Java code, but closer. You're never using any of your variables, so just don't use variables: `new Foo(params); new Foo(differentParams);`. This is ugly as hell, because a constructor shouldn't have side effects, and shouldn't escape `this`, but that's another issue.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

> This question came up in my mind when thinking about memory and whether or not doing case 2 would save more memory compared to case 1 since you are not declaring a new variable each time.

On Android, the memory is severely limited, IIRC an app can use only 20 MB. One variable may take 4 bytes, and you save two variables, i.e., 8 bytes. This means that when you write 250,000 such classes, you save 2 MB, i.e., 10% of available memory.

*Are you going to write a quarter million of such classes?*

I hope, you are not.

But then, it doesn't matter as local variables exist only when the method is called and nobody cares about 8 bytes.

Moreover, your code gets processed by an optimizing compiler, which doesn't transform your code line by line. So it's possible, that there's no difference in the generated code for your two versions.

*So please, don't try optimizing irrelevant details.*

Write proper code instead. As you've been said, "a constructor shouldn't have side effects, and shouldn't escape `this`".

I'd suggest something like this:

```
class Main { // class names are always UpperCamelCase
    private List<Foo> bar = new ArrayList; // "private"

    public static main(String[] args) { 
        new Main().go(); // leave the static context ASAP
    }

    private void go() {
        bar.add(new Foo(params));
        bar.add(new Foo(differentParams));
        bar.add(new Foo(....));
    }
}
```

No magic there. The constructor constructs and does nothing else.

Everything gets added explicitly... this may get verbose, but then you'd just write a method encapsulation common operations.